# Close a browser tab opened by Android app

Tags: javascript, android

I have an issue where I'm asking my app to open a browser looking at my Server.

From that server page, The user can perform some stuff on an existing site, then redirects the user to a URL that the App catches and the App continues as normal.

The lifecycle looks like this:

```
App -> Web Site -> App
```

However, after the life cycle of the app and the app is closed, the webpage is still open in the browser (on the page where the redirect to the app occurred).

It's apparently difficult via javascript to close a tab which wasn't opened by javascript? (In my case, the tab was opened by the app, not by a different tab). Is there any way to get around this?

(I'm aware I could use a WebView, but WebViews are buggy, manufacturer specific, security holes that I want to avoid)

Comment: You could look into Chrome custom tabs, they might have something: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs